# eBay FindingAPI::findItemsItemsAdvanced to return item specifics

Tags: ebay-api

I am using the [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) API of the eBay Finding API. The call is working fine but I need it to return item specifics, you know the details that you see at the top of an eBay, such as : `EAN, MPN, ISBN, Manufacturer` etc. I am specifically interested in getting the `MPN` field.

I by default the item attributes fields where these items are stored aren't returned. The documentation seems ambiguous (to me) about this particular field stating that it is not controlled by the output selector.

How do I inform the API that I would like to have these fields returned?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

findItemsAdvanced does not return the item specifics. You can instead use the [itemID](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Response.searchResult.item.itemId) that is returned in the search results and use this to make a separate call to [GetSingleItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) in the Shopping service. This call will return the item specifics as long as you pass *ItemSpecifics* in the [IncludeSelector](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Request.IncludeSelector) field.